# Insert into sql_variant column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a value to sql_variant column in sql server from an xml column

ex.

```
 INSERT INTO 
  [dbo].[TestColumn]
 (
  Id,
  Attribute,
  AttributeValue
 )
 SELECT 
  Id, 
  'TestName', 
  CAST(CustomColumns.query('//TestName') AS nVarchar(MAX))
 FROM 
  [dbo].[Clmnt] (NOLOCK)
```

I got this error,

```
Operand type clash: nvarchar(max) is incompatible with sql_variant
```

Anybody has any clue on this, How do I easily insert a value in sql_variant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sql_variant can not store nvarchar(max)

[sql_variant (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx)

That link says that the following the types of values cannot be stored by using sql_variant:

```
varchar(max)
varbinary(max)
nvarchar(max)
xml
text
ntext
image
timestamp
sql_variant
geography
hierarchyid
geometry
User-defined types
```

Comment: Agreed. So how I can insert data?

Comment: do not use a sql_variant column, perhaps nvarchar(max) or even xml.  Although it does appear that you are using an value-attribute design, you don't explain your schema in the original question, so it is a little hard to expand.

Comment: you could try: `CAST(CustomColumns.query('//TestName') AS nVarchar(8000))`, which will only work if your XML is under 8000 characters.

Comment: varchar(max) is not working limitation to Varchar(8012). Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

Sql_variant does support strings.  For SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
nvarchar(4000) but not nvarchar(max).
varchar(8000) but not varchar(max)
```

The docs I had found were a bit vague on these thresholds.